# UIMenu doesn't pop up

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uimenu

I'm trying to pop up a `UIMenu` once the user press the correct `UIBarButton`, but the problem is the UIMenu doesn't pop up and I don't know why, would be cool if you guys can help me with that.

- I also added the comment code to show you all the tries.
- My problem is when I set up the `UIBarButton` but not sure. BTW! i didn't use computed properties due to the fact that I couldn't edit them when I use that way, so I just used a normal stored variable.

myCode:

```
// MARK: - UIBarButtonItem Creation and Configuration
    
     func configureUIButtons() {
        
//        let toolbarButtonItems = [
//            customTitleBarButtonItem,
//            flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem,
//            deleteBarButtonItem
//        ]
        
        let toolbarButtonItems = [
            markBarButtonItem, flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem, deleteBarButtonItem
        ]
        
        toolBar.setItems(toolbarButtonItems, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    
    var deleteBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(NotificationsViewController.deleteButtonItemClicked(_:)))
    
    
    
//    var deleteBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
//        let deleteBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(NotificationsViewController.deleteButtonItemClicked(_:)));
//
//        return deleteBarButtonItem
//
//    }

    
    var flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    
    
//    var flexibleSpaceBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem {
//        return UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
//                               target: nil,
//                               action: nil)
//    }
    
    
    
    var markBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mark", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(NotificationsViewController.markButtonItemClicked(_:)))
    
    
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    @objc
    func deleteButtonItemClicked(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("Delete Button is clicked \(barButtonItem).")
    }

    
    @objc
    func markButtonItemClicked(_ barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem ) -> UIMenu {
        print("Mark is pressed")


        let markMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
                    UIAction(title: "Flag", image: UIImage(systemName: "flag")) { action in
                        print("Flag is pressed")
                    },
                    UIAction(title: "Mark as Unread", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope.badge")) { action in
                        print("Mark as Unread is pressed")
                    },
                ])

                return markMenu

    }
    
    
//    func menuItems() -> UIMenu {
//        let markMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
//            UIAction(title: "Flag", image: UIImage(systemName: "flag")) { action in
//                print("Flag is pressed")
//            },
//            UIAction(title: "Mark as Unread", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope.badge")) { action in
//                print("Mark as Unread is pressed")
//            },
//        ])
//
//        return markMenu
//    }
//
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the proper initializer for the menu.

```swift
let markMenu = UIMenu(title: "", children: [
    UIAction(title: "Flag", image: UIImage(systemName: "flag")) { action in
        print("Flag is pressed")
    },
    UIAction(title: "Mark as Unread", image: UIImage(systemName: "envelope.badge")) { action in
        print("Mark as Unread is pressed")
    },
])
let markBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Mark", image: nil, primaryAction: nil, menu: markMenu)
let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)))
toolBar.setItems([markBarButtonItem], animated: true)
```

Comment: I see, will try that, btw UIMenu only works for iOS 14 users? is there something to do about it? I mean what would I do if i got users who use iOS 12? 

Answer (score 0):

Use "self" instead of the name of your view controller (NotificationsViewController) when you add the selector in your bar button initialization, or just refer to the function name directly if you don't like putting self. in front of methods and properties when it's not required.